# Android AudioManager get wrong values

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I faced the above problem.

I use this piece of code to get ring and notification volumes

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
int currentNotif = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
```

This run very well UNTIL i get a call. 
It returns different values under calling circumstances. (phone call). And by that i mean that if i do not having a phone call this values are for example :

```
currentVolume = 7 
currentNotif  = 7
```

and while my phone call these values become

```
currentVolume = 1 
currentNotif  = 7
```

or

```
 currentVolume = 1 
currentNotif  = 1
```

I use Samsung galaxy s3 device with android 4.1.2.

**The question is:**

Why that happens. Is it OS bug or Samsung bug?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is _"some code"_ and _"different values"_?

Comment: Do you get the lower values for the entire duration of the call? It's quite common to mute or attenuate the `RING` stream when a call is answered, so that you don't get any remaining part of the ringtone blasted into your ear as you put the phone up against your ear. It should be set back to its original value after a short period of time, but that's an implementation-specific behavior (it's entirely possible that the value isn't restored until you end the call on some phones).

Comment: You are probably right. I will debug it and i will tell you for sure. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug but rather by design. When the STREAM_VOICE_CALL is in progress, all other STREAM will duck at reduced volume. The user experience is such that during phone call, all other audio stream that didn't mute (music, ring, notification) will be played at lower volume.

AudioPolicy behavior like this can be introduced by OS, Manufacturer, or Carrier when customizing the Android OS. For this particular case, I have seen it across all Note2 (added by Samsung), but haven't seen it on S3. If you can, please share the carrier of the S3 you have.